# Can IOS app do things even when it is not working at all (Killed/Non-running state)

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I Did lots of BG tasks in the past, But Trying to get data when app is killed (Even when user is giving Always permission) seems not to work.
I wonder if there is a solution for that.
To make things clear, I am not talking at the moment when app change from Active or Background even to suspended mode. I'm talking about if the user is using the app and set permissions but then kills the app and after that i need every hour to get data from the user and send data to them.

1. Is there a way to do that?
2. Can a Today widget help me with that? Does a Today widget "lives" all the time and i can get that from it 24/7?

Whet is working is CLLocation manager. This is working even when the app is killed. But only when the user is changing a location.
I need that to work when the user is in the same place also.

Non of the other methods work. Not BGTask (I need every hour on the hour and not when apple decide to do things), Nor Silent Push Notification for some reason (Regular ones work, but i Don't want to bother the user with a push every hour just for getting and sending data).

Sorry there is no code to show as this is a very general question. But i think that is very important one to many people and can't find an answer for that.

Comment: Short answer, you can't do it. If the user terminates your app then the only thing that will relaunch it is location services or a voip push (but you have to report an incoming phone call). Even while your app is suspended you wouldn't get background fetch to execute every hour.

Comment: 10x @Paulw11 what about Silent push notifications? I can send one every hour and then i can wake that app into the background to send HTTP request? From the docs it seems that i can, But i'm trying a group notification from firebase and it seems like it is working only on one device. All other devices are not receiving it. It is so weird.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but if the app is terminated then it won’t be relaunched to receive the notification

Comment: @Paulw11 I am talking only about an app that was terminated (Non-running state). If the app is in the background or even inactive or suspended, I can do many all those things. But the issue is with an app that is terminated, Actively by the user or by the system and then I still need to get the users data and send them data without interrupting the user. You said YES and then explained that i can't, I need it to collect a location and send HTTP request for each silent push notification so i will know what the user is and give them data for that location. So i didn't understand it. 10x

Comment: I already explained in my first comment that you can’t do what you want. I assumed that when you were talking about silent push you were talking about the case where the app wasn’t terminated.

Comment: @Paulw11 OK, Weird... I actually am getting them on one device when the app is terminated and the phone is on my night stand, Very weird... What about using the Today extension as the source of truth or is that also being terminated when i'm not in the Today extensions screen?

Comment: You won’t get them if you have terminated the app, only if it is suspended.